# H must be the handle to a figure or figure descendent Matlab

Tags: matlab, function, class, user-interface

I'm calling GUI function in matlab's `classdef`but it gives error of "H must be the handle to a figure or figure descendent." in  `guihandles(GUI);`
How can I call function of GUI in matlab's class?
The working of the class is perfect by the way, but it gives error then figure is closed.
My class code:

```
classdef GUIclass < handle  

    properties (Access = private)
        gui_h;
    end
    methods

        function obj = GUIclass
            guihandles(GUI);
        end

    end


end
```

Comment: Is the GUI variable supposed to be `obj.gui_h`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function guihandles(h) expects a handle. If the handle specified by h (in your case, `GUI`) is closed then it is no longer valid. You can check to see if GUI is a valid handle before using it with `ishandle(h)` or `ishandle(GUI)`.

See the following code:

```
close all;
h = 1;

% We just closed everything, so we expect handle h=1 to be bad:
if ishandle(h)
    disp('Is a valid handle');
else
    disp('Is not a valid handle');
end

% Now make the figure (we specify '1' so that will make h okay
figure(1);

% check to see if h is valid:
if ishandle(h)
    disp('Is a valid handle');
else
    disp('Is not a valid handle');
end
```

Comment: I resolved 50% but not fully, `if ishandle(GUI)
    guihandles(GUI);
end` is added so that when GUI close, its fine but when any option of GUI is pressed and then close, it gives the same error, How can I fully checked this?

Comment: @AhsanAli It is likely that you either are 1) using one of the handles returned by `guihandles(...)` without first checking if it `ishandle(h)`, or you have a callback that is causing problems.

Comment: Yeah I think callback problem occurring, but how to fix that.?

Comment: @AhsanAli You might 1) check all handles used in the callbacks 2) check the figure in the callback and if its not valid unhook the  callback and exit fast 3) see if you can add a callback to the figures closing and unhook all your callbacks.